# Which libraries is the layout of The Library based on?

Tags: behind-the-scenes, real-location, the-librarians

The Library is the main location in *The Librarians*. While the Annex entrance is located at the base of the St. John's Bridge in Portland, there is little information available on what inspired the library's​ layout.

It is possible this entire scene may be CGI from a small filming set given its infinite size, but is there any real life location that such set is based on? The layout seems quite complicated to be completely fabricated from scratch.

[image: character in fictional library]

Comment: It seems to be a CGI mash-up of [Dublin Library](http://wcsa.world/Userfiles/Upload/images/f76b746f06c2356931222de816f32297.jpg) and [Annenberg Hall, Harvard](https://s3.amazonaws.com/secretsaucefiles/photos/images/000/106/361/large/spooncoverphoto.jpg?1485364460)